# Getting the file name from query string to create a virtual page on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a PDF file viewer web page and instead of manually creating a web page for each PDF document, I want the page to get the file names attached to its Url as a query string and adds the file name to a JavaScript value in the page.

For example:

```
http://example.com/FileViewer.aspx?file=GetStarted.pdf
```

"GetStarted.pdf" should be captured and used as a value in the script, so each request to http://example.com/FileViewer.aspx with the file name attached to it should respond back with a page on the fly that shows the PDF document.

Never done this before with C# and I don't have any sample code, but any leads and/or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a [sample code](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Display-PDF-File-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-Window.aspx)

Comment: I also [found this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Pass-Data-Values-from-one-page-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx), looks like it can also be done with jQuery.